# How to correctly submit a search form and display the result in an independent page

Tags: php, search, mysql, forms, select

I have part search function in my WordPress website which uses dynamic dependent select box.

However, now I have the following problem:

**If only select the first one box, or select the first two boxes, and click the `Search` button, it successfully jumps to the result page.**

**However, if continuously select the third box, it jumps to a page with the same URL as the result page but the content of the homepage.**

**I check the Chrome Console and see this error:**

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I have all the relative code below.

**1. font-end part of the select boxes:**

```
<form class="select-boxes" action="<?php echo site_url("/part-search-result/"); ?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <?php include(__DIR__.'/inc/part-search.php'); ?>
</form>
```

**2. `part-search.php`**

```
<?php
    include( __DIR__.'/db-config.php' );
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ps_manufact WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY manufact_name ASC");
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>

<select name="manufacturer" id="manufact" onchange="manufactText(this)">
    <option value="">Select Manufacturer</option>
    <?php
        if($rowCount > 0){
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                echo '<option value="'.$row['manufact_id'].'">'.$row['manufact_name'].'</option>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<option value="">Manufacturer Not Available</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
<input id="manufacturer_text" type="hidden" name="manufacturer_text" value=""/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function manufactText(ddl) {
        document.getElementById('manufacturer_text').value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>

<select name="type" id="type" onchange="typeText(this)">
    <option value="">Select Manufacturer First</option>
</select>
<input id="type_text" type="hidden" name="type_text" value=""/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function typeText(ddl) {
        document.getElementById('type_text').value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>

<select name="year" id="year" onchange="yearText(this)">
    <option value="">Select Type First</option>
</select>
<input id="year_text" type="hidden" name="year_text" value=""/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function yearText(ddl) {
        document.getElementById('year_text').value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>

<select name="model" id="model" onchange="modelText(this)">
    <option value="">Select Year First</option>
</select>
<input id="model_text" type="hidden" name="model_text" value=""/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function modelText(ddl) {
        document.getElementById('model_text').value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>

<input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Search">


<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#manufact').on('change',function(){
            var manufactID = $(this).val();
            if(manufactID){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'<?php echo home_url('wp-content/themes/myTheme/inc/ajax-data.php') ?>',
                    data:'manufact_id='+manufactID,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#type').html(html);
                        $('#year').html('<option value="">Select Type First</option>');
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#type').html('<option value="">Select Manufact First</option>');
                $('#year').html('<option value="">Select Type First</option>');
            }
        });

        $('#type').on('change',function(){
            var typeID = $(this).val();
            if(typeID){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'<?php echo home_url('wp-content/themes/myTheme/inc/ajax-data.php') ?>',
                    data:'type_id='+typeID,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#year').html(html);
                        $('#model').html('<option value="">Select Year First</option>');
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#year').html('<option value="">Select Type First</option>');
                $('#model').html('<option value="">Select Year First</option>');
            }
        });

        $('#year').on('change',function(){
            var yearID = $(this).val();
            if(yearID){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'<?php echo home_url('wp-content/themes/myTheme/inc/ajax-data.php') ?>',
                    data:'year_id='+yearID,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#model').html(html);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#model').html('<option value="">Select Year First</option>');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**3. `ajax-data.php`**

```
<?php

include( __DIR__.'/db-config.php' );

if(isset($_POST["manufact_id"]) && !empty($_POST["manufact_id"])){
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ps_type WHERE manufact_id = ".$_POST['manufact_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY type_name ASC");

    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select Type</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['type_id'].'">'.$row['type_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Type Not Available</option>';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["type_id"]) && !empty($_POST["type_id"])){
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ps_year WHERE type_id = ".$_POST['type_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY year_name ASC");

    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select Year</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['year_id'].'">'.$row['year_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Year Not Available</option>';
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["year_id"]) && !empty($_POST["year_id"])){
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ps_model WHERE year_id = ".$_POST['year_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY model_name ASC");

    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select Model</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['model_id'].'">'.$row['model_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Model Not Available</option>';
    }
}

?>
```

**4. `part-search-result.php`**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $clauses = array();
    if (isset($_POST['manufacturer_text']) && !empty($_POST['manufacturer_text'])) {
        $clauses[] = "`manufacturer` = '{$_POST['manufacturer_text']}'";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['type_text']) && !empty($_POST['type_text'])) {
        $clauses[] = "`type` = '{$_POST['type_text']}'";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['year_text']) && !empty($_POST['year_text'])) {
        $clauses[] = "`year` = '{$_POST['year_text']}'";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['model_text']) && !empty($_POST['model_text'])) {
        $clauses[] = "`model` = '{$_POST['model_text']}'";
    }
    $where = !empty( $clauses ) ? ' where '.implode(' and ',$clauses ) : '';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_products` ". $where;
    $result = filterTable($sql);
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_products` WHERE `manufacturer`=''";
    $result = filterTable($sql);
}

function filterTable($sql) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "i2235990_wp2");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>

    <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="products" class="row list-group">
        <?php while ( $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ): ?>
            <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <?php
                        echo '<img name="product-image" class="group list-group-image hvr-bob" src=' . $rows['image_url'] . ' width="400px" height="250px" alt="" />';
                    ?>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
                        <?php
                            echo "Manufacturer:\t".$rows['manufacturer'].'<br>';
                            echo "Type:\t".$rows['type'].'<br>';
                            echo "Year:\t".$rows['year'].'<br>';
                            echo "Model:\t".$rows['model'].'<br>';
                            echo '<br>';
                            echo "Description:\t".$rows['description'].'<br>';
                        ?>
                        </h4>                           
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I thought there might be problem with not using POST correctly in WordPress, I found a tutorial: [Handling POST Requests the WordPress Way](https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/)

However, I already used `action` to jump to the result page, I have no idea how to solve my problem.

Comment: Are you sure about db_config.php ? Why not use global $wpdb ? https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb . Are you sure about the link in the action, did you set the permalink to get part-search-result.php ?

Comment: Technically you can achieve all of this without using MySQL queries and by using only WP queries

Comment: Since you're basically not writing using any of the built-in WordPress functionalities, I'm not sure this belongs in the WPSE.. Why not use what WP has already done for you

Answer (score 2):

To create your own independent search functionality, follow these steps.

**1-** You need a form to send the data for you. This is a simple form that can do this for you:

```
<form method="post" name="car-select" action="<?php echo site_url('/my-page/'); ?>">
    <select name="make">
        <option value="benz">Benz</option>
        <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select name="type">
        <option value="sedan">Sedan</option>
        <option value="coupe">Coupe</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Find my dream car!"/>
</form>
```

Which `/my-page/` is the slug for the page we are going to create later.

**2-** A function to handle the search results. Take a look at this basic function that searches the cars based on the entered values:

```
function my_custom_search() {
    $car_make = $_POST['make'];
    $car_type = $_POST['type'];
    $car_query = new WP_Query ( array (
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'car_make',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $car_make,
            ),
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'car_type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $car_type,
            ),
         ),
    ));
    if ($car_query->have_posts) {
        while($car_query->have_posts()){
            $car_query->the_post();
            get_template_part('WHATEVER TEMPLATE YOU WANT TO USE');
        }
    }
    // Pagination goes here
}
```

**3-** A page to show your search results. Remember the slug in the first requirement? Create a page in your template's directory and name it like `page-my-search-template.php`. Then include this function in your new page template, wherever you wish:

`my_custom_search();`

You should then create a page with `my-page` slug (the one in the form's action), using the template you just made.

Now, every submission of the form will trigger a search query and display the results in your very own search template!

**WAIT !! I want my pagination !!**

You can implement your own pagination in the search function, however i recommend using [WP-PageNavi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) for those who don't have enough skill to write a pagination script. Install the plugin, and set the query like this:

`wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $car_query ));`

This way you have a pagination for your custom search page, nice and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any mySQL queries. WordPress's default search is submitting "s" with the URL. You can accomplish it with a simple form with hidden inputs.

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="careers_search">
  <input type="text" name="search-career" value="Search...">
  <input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This form will submit itself on the same URL.
After submissions this is what supposed to happen-

```
<?php
  if( isset( $_GET['careers_search'] ) ) {
    // Your code goes here...
  }
?>
```